# Grails: could not resolve List property from a subquery

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I want a property that returns a list from a subquery. How should it be mapped? Here is my domains; the first one is:

```
class Ticket {
    String name     
    List companies

    static hasMany = [
        ticketCompanies: ticketCompany]

    Set<Company> getCompanies() {
        ticketCompany.findAllByTicket(this).collect { it.company } as Set
    }

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'ticket_id'      
        companies formula: '(SELECT tc.company_id FROM ticket_company tc WHERE tc.ticket_id = ticket_id)'
        version false
    } // end mapping


    static constraints = { /* etc */}
}
```

The second domain:

```
class Company {

    String name

    static hasMany = [ticketCompanies: ticketCompany]

    Set<Ticket> getTickets() {
        TicketCompany.findAllByCompany(this).collect { it.ticket } as Set
    }

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'company_id'
        version false
    }   

    static constraints = { /* bla bla bla */ }
}
```

And this is ticket_company description (MySQL):

```
Field   |Type   |Null   |Key    |Default    |Extra
ticket_id   |int(11)    |NO |   PRI |   |       
company_id  |bigint(11) |NO |   PRI |   |
```

This legacy is the reason why I included a getCompanies() method. Here goes my service method:

```
def listTicketsAndTheirCompanies() {

    def tickets = Ticket.withCriteria() {
        resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP

        /* some criteria here */
        /* we can put some createAlias here, 
           but I still don't know how */

        order 'id'

        projections {               
            property 'id'                   , 'id'
            /* etc */                   
            property 'companies'                , 'companies'           
        }
    }

    return tickets
}
```

And here is my ticketCompany unusual relationship:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder

class TicketCompany implements Serializable {

    Ticket ticket
    Company company

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        builder.append company
        builder.append ticket
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (other == null) return false
        def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
        builder.append company, other.company
        builder.append ticket, other.ticket
        builder.isEquals()
    }

    /* here we have get, create, Ticket removeAll, Company removeAll methods... */  

    static mapping = {
        ticket column: "ticket_id"
        company column: "company_id"
        id composite: ["ticket", "company"]     
        version false
    }
}
```

Am I mapping this relationship correctly? Am I trying to access `List companies` correctly?

PS: Sorry for any typo or missing information. I had to translate and edit a lot of code, but I can re-edit and help the community to help me as you ask me more information.

Comment: you might want to take a look at https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html

Comment: But how can I use a namedQuery in GORM, I mean, in my service method?

Answer (score 1):

I found a valid solution for me. A property for domain `Ticket` called `String companiesStr`, a computed property mapped as

```
    static mapping = {
        ticket column: "ticket_id"
        company column: "company_id"
        id composite: ["ticket", "company"] 
        companiesStr formula: '(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ae.ticket_id) ' + 
                             'FROM ticket_company tc ' + 
                             'WHERE tc.ticket_id = ticket_id ' + 
                             'GROUP BY tc.ticket_id)'
        version false
    }
```

Hence I have a new result, as I call `companyStr` from my service method:

```
def listTicketsAndTheirCompanies(String aCertainTicketId) {

    def tickets = Ticket.withCriteria() {
        resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP

        /* we can put some createAlias here... */

        ilike 'companiesStr', "%${aCertainTicketId}%" 
        /* that's a failable criteria; any idea for a regex 
           which match a mySQL GROUP_CONCAT string below? */

        order 'id'

        projections {               
            property 'id', 'id'
            /* etc */                   
            property 'companiesStr', 'companiesStr'            
        }
    }

    tickets.each {
        println "${it.id} : ${it.companiesStr}"
    }

    /* 
     87602 : 1615,1764,1771,1772,1775,1776
     65073 : 1615 
     */

    return tickets
}
```

This is not the ideal answer, as I have a string as an answer and I need to use it in my criteria. Looking for a piece of string in this generated string could fail.